# Centre of mass and conservation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

> A bullet of mass $25\,\rm{g}$ is fired horizontally into a ballistic pendulum of mass $5.0\,\rm{kg}$ and gets embedded in. If the centre of the pendulum rises by a distance of $10\, \rm{cm}$, find the speed of the bullet.

‌In the above types of questions, why we don't include both the initial and final velocities of the bullet while finding the initial kinetic energy of the system in conservation of energy (COE)?

Comment: The structure of pendulum deforms when the bullet enters it, this causes loss of energy and hence kinetic energy conservation is not valid. However if you could account for material losses, then you could do it

Comment: Deforms *permanently* we should say. Also, bullet might deform. Noise and heat may be generated.

Answer (score 3):

> In the above types questions why we don't include the( initial and
> final both) velocities of bullet while finding the initial kinetic
> energy of the system in (COE) conservation of energy

In the example you gave, **kinetic energy is not conserved**. During the completely inelastic collision some kinetic energy is spent on permanently deforming the pendulum and the bullet (and maybe some noise and heat from friction).

You need to use conservation of momentum here to find the velocity of pendulum plus bullet just after the collision. Then apply conservation of energy to relate that velocity to height of swing.

---

Somewhat idealised, let $v_0$ be the bullet's speed, $m$ its mass, $v_1$ the post-collision speed of bullet plus pendulum and $M$ the mass of the pendulum, then conservation of momentum pre and post collision says:

$$mv_0=(m+M)v_1$$

Then apply conservation of energy:

$$\frac12(m+M)v_1^2=(m+M)gH$$

Combine the equations to extricate $v_0$ as a function of $H$ (the purpose of a ballistic pendulum)

Comment: purely homework based question please avoid the questions like that

Comment: @Yuvraj This is a *conceptual* question, so it is permitted under the site's homework policy. OTOH, if the OP did a little research, they probably would not have needed to ask this question...

Comment: @PM2Ring: thanks for clarifying that.